# Android Database Helper [ Syntax Token Error]

Tags: android, sqlite

i just started practicing android and sqlite database. i came across a very strange problem which i am unable to rectify.kindly help me out.
 Below i have out my DataBaseHelper class. (Description follows after the code block...)

```
package com.dialog.test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

//The Androids default system path of your application database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.dialog.test/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "butName";

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
this.myContext = context;
}

//Create Database
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
if(dbExist){
//do nothing - database already exist
}else{
this.getReadableDatabase();
try {
copyDataBase();
} catch (IOException e) {
throw new Error("Error copying database");
}
}
}

//check Database
private boolean checkDataBase(){
SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
try{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}catch(SQLiteException e){
//database doest exist yet.
}
if(checkDB != null){
checkDB.close();
}
return checkDB != null;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

//Open your local db as the input stream
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
// Path to the just created empty db
String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

//Open the empty db as the output stream
OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;
while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

//Close the streams
myOutput.flush();
myOutput.close();
myInput.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

//Open the database
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

if(myDataBase != null)
myDataBase.close();

super.close();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

Now when i create an object for this class i get the following error

```
package com.dialog.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.database.SQLException;

public class VarbClass {
//syntax token error ";" in the below line
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper();
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
try {
myDbHelper.createDataBase();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
throw new Error("Unable to create database");
}
try {
myDbHelper.openDataBase();
}catch(SQLException sqle){
throw sqle;
}
}
```

error on line 9 in the code above...
//syntax token error ";" in the below line
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper();
kindly help me resolve my issue thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of VarbClass is obviously wrong. The 'try' block should be inside a method or a 'static' block. Try this:

```
public class VarbClass {
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;


public VarbClass() {
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    try{
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }

    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } 
    catch (SQLException sqle){
        throw sqle;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: hey ash, i get the error "the constructor DataBaseHelper is undefined"

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You get this error because you pass VarbClass instance to the constructor for DataBaseHelper. You need to pass a Context. Add a context parameter to the constructor ('public VarbClass()' should become 'public VarbClass(Context context)') and pass it on to the DataBaseHelper, instead of 'this'.

Comment: Ash i am sorry but i am new to this can you please brief me on this ?? Thank You

Comment: Each Android application has a Context. Instances of this class represent environment of the application. Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) out for more information. SQLiteOpenHelper (and DataBaseHelper, obviously) needs context in order to open the database. Context can be obtained from any Activity (see `getApplicationContext()`). If VarbClass is used from an Activity, it should be instantiated something like this: `new VarbClass(getApplicationContext())`, and then VarbClass will be able to pass the context on to the DataBaseHelper.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't write your statements into a method, instead directly inside the class.
You *have* to wrap them into a method. You can keep the member variable though, depending on if it makes sense to you.

This would be easily spottable by indenting your code. Example:

```
public class VarbClass {
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper();
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

    try {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch(SQLException sqle) {
        throw sqle;
    }
}
```

That does not look correct from the layout itself.

The two lines at the top *(2 and 3)* are correct, but not efficient. You create a new `DataBaseHelper` via the default constructor and overwrite this in the next line with one created from a different constructor. You can merge these to

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
```

Has exactly the same effect while using less resources.

Answer (score 0):

correct your VarbClass code with following code. you have done wrong in DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(null);

```
package com.dialog.test;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.database.SQLException;

    public class VarbClass {
    //syntax token error ";" in the below line
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = null;
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    try {
    myDbHelper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new Error("Unable to create database");
    }
    try {
    myDbHelper.openDataBase();
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
    throw sqle;
    }

}
```